# How can I import my own build OpenCV lib form python 2.7 and windows10?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, opencv

For a school project I'm trying to use openCV with contrib with python 2.7 on windows.

So I've built the library with Visual Studio, put all the *.dll* files in the same directory of *python.exe* and set the *OPEN_CV* path var like this: [Path variable openCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Bim.png)

But when I try to import openCV in project I still have this ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c8b25dfd3576> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

Thank you fot your help.

Comment: Does it have file named opencv*.pyd? It is essentially dll with python bindings. It should be in path for "import cv2" to succeed.

Comment: it's work ! 
Thank you